# Qt Designer generate C++ code

Tags: c++, python, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

Is it possible to see C++ code with Qt Designer ? I can draw my interface and have it saved as a .ui file. Also, I can generate python code from .ui file using a .bat file. But I cannot view C++/Qt code generated from the UI, which I would like to get.

I looked for it and all I can find is doc. about how to generate the python from the .ui, which I can do but is not what I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Usually the C++ code is generated in a `ui_...h` file by the [`uic`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/uic.html) tool - is this what you are looking for, or do you want to have Qt Designer directly create the C++ code (probably by calling `uic`)?

Comment: There is an item View Code in menu Form. I thought it was for generating C++ code. How can i do to see/generate C++ code from the .uic file ? thanks!

Comment: I think "they"'ve stripped this feature from Qt Designer. I remember it in an older version, but nowadays I'd recommend switching to Qt Creator. It also has an integrated Designer-View.

Comment: @andrjas Its still there in 5.0.2

Comment: ok, my bad. I thought about code editing actually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The menu item "Form/View Code" is exactly what you expect - it shows the generated C++ code:

[image: Screenshot from Qt designer]

As you can see from the comments in the generated file, Qt designer also uses `uic` (the [*Qt User Interface Compiler*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/uic.html)) to generate the code preview.

You can verify if `uic` works properly by manually creating the source code:

- save your form to a `.ui` file, e.g. `sample.ui`
- Run `uic -o sample.h sample.ui` from a command shell
- `sample.h` then contains the generated source code