# Parse xml file and dynamically generate c++ code to build a panel(UI)

Tags: c++, xml, qt, user-interface, xml-parsing

I need to parse one xml file using c++ and dynamically populate a QT UI.

Any help in terms of tutorial, links, suggestions, source code example will be deeply appreciated. I have gone through most of the similar stack overflow links but its not helpful much.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hm, what about letting QtDesigner give you the code?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286166/qt-designer-generate-c-code

Comment: Does your XML files are Qt's ui files ?

Comment: Alex @ No.. currently I have an example xml file which is created by xml spy software..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [QXmlStreamReader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html) and the [Bookmarks example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-streambookmarks-example.html).

Basically what you want to do is open an XML file (using QFile), read it line by line and create the necessary UI-object (don't forget to close the file afterwards).

Let's assume your XML file looks something like this:

```
<ui>
    <mainwindow width="800" height="600">
        <label position="center">FOO</label>
        ...
    </mainwindow>
</ui>
```

You'd use something like [readNextStartElement()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#readNextStartElement) to read to `<mainwindow ..>`, read its attributes and call a method that creates a QMainWindow using the data you read. Then [readNextStartElement()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#readNextStartElement) to `<label ...>`, call a method that creates the label and add it to the main window according to the atributes, and so on.